# How to scale each container on Docker Multi Container deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, scale, amazon-ecs

I have deployed a Multi-container Docker on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it is working as it is supposed to be, I have configured all the load balancers that I need for the communication of each Docker container.

But when it comes to scaling a container I do not know how to do it. The Elastic Beanstalk provides a single EC2 instance that I am able to scale, but if I scale it, all of my Docker images will be scale when, for instance, only one has the real need to be scaled.

[image: EB instances]

I am also aware that when an environment is created on EB, AWS also created a cluster on ECS, and inside that cluster, I have one task assigned for all of my docker images, but cannot scale them.

[image: ECS cluster task]

Does anyone know how to scale only one Docker image on this scenario?

Comment: Looking at the docs, it appears that Elastic Beanstalk deploys all your containers as a single ECS task? If so, there isn't any way to scale one of those containers separately from all the others. If you want more control over that you should probably be using ECS directly instead of Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, it seems that EB is not the right call, I will study the ECS to see if it covers my requirement